# Visual Studio 2010 Test Controller Load Test Database Configuration Failure?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, load-testing

I am attempting to install Visual Studio 2010 Agents for Test Controller / Test Agents so I can create Load Tests on my local machine.  When attempting to install the Test Controller I recieve the following message in the configuration summarry

[image]

```
From the installation log I found the following error messages:
The existing connection string for controller MyComputerName:6901 is {this is blank}
```

> System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.WebStress.LoadTestDatabaseCounterWriter.IsDatabaseUpgradeFromRTMNeeded(System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection)'.
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.TestControllerHelper.CreateAndUpgradeLoadTestSchemaIfRequired(String
>   loadTestConnectionString, String directoryContainingSchemaFile)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.ConfigCore.ControllerConfiguration.UpdateLoadTestDatabase(ControllerConfigurationUpdatePack
>   updatePack, DelegateStatusUpdate statusListener)

```
Failed to configure load test database.
```

Comment: Have you created an SQL database for the load testing yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem solved!
Briefly, only Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1 is missing, and a DLL doesn't contain a method that is invoked by the Test Controller Configuration Tool.

Solution: install VS 2010 Service Pack 1.
Reason: Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.LoadTest.DLL does not contain a Database checker method that is invoked by the configuration tool, so an exception is thrown, and the configuration is failing. After upgrading to SP1, the DLL updates successfully and the missing method can be found there.